# Condo grounding connections between 230v and 115v service

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding

My apartment in Spain has a 230v entry power distribution panel. There is a ground wire run to all 230v outlets. The panel also feeds a large, ie greater than 30kva step down 230v to 115v floating transformer which in turn feeds respective outlets. But these outlets don’t have a ground wire  connected. Can I create a 115v ground by jumpering to the existing 230v ground?

Comment: Maybe "greater than 25#" is obvious to the electricians in the house, but it's not quite so obvious to me what that means. An [edit] to better explain that wouldn't hurt.

Comment: you already asked this ... if you have additional info, then please add it to your first question and request it to be reopened ... https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/265377/how-to-provide-residence-electrical-ground-connections-to-dual-voltage-receptacl

Comment: I'm voting to close this new question because it's a duplicate of your existing question: [How to provide residence electrical ground connections to dual voltage receptacles](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/265377/how-to-provide-residence-electrical-ground-connections-to-dual-voltage-receptacl)

Comment: It’s floating. Note edit to 25kva transformer size.

Comment: My initial question was closed and as a first time member, I read that it was better to re-ask the question including additional details.

Comment: Can edit your questions and add any additional details/information.  It is better to edit them into the question than add them in a comment.

Comment: If the 115V side of the transofmer is "floating" (isolated) is there any benefit to providing earth-connecting ground pins at the outlets? Does that do anything? OTOH, if one side of the secondary coil is earthed for this very purpose, we REALLY have to wonder why the outlets don't already have ground wires. This is in a shared building ... I would consult someone familiar and licensed with this particular kind of installation before, or actually instead of doing anything

Comment: I know learning the ropes on a new platform (especially a non-forum one like this one) is a challenge.  It would have been better to [edit] the original question to improve it, but that particular one got locked in a limbo because mods tried to reject a migration.  The topic does belong here IMO, it's not a better fit for electronics.se merely because it needed improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you can do that. The ground is not power carrying wire. It is only there to protect you from shocks in case a device fails and leaks to device housing that you touch. Since it is not a part of electrical circuit the ground does not care where it comes from.

Comment: I'd like to know what "floating" in the question means.  If it means the obvious, I think doing this achieves nothing, in fact provides a false safety factor.  Grounding needs to be addressed holistically by someone who *really* knows what they're doing.

Comment: Existing 230v outlets have a ground contact that is wired to from the utility input breaker box. The 115v outlets from the 30+ years old transformer are not showing that they have a ground, ie there’s no ground wire connected to them.

Comment: @jay613 why are you asking me, ask the OP

Answer (score 2):

In the future, you should edit your original question rather than ask near-duplicate questions.  The way we moved it between forums was weird and I'll address that with mods.

It really depends on how the transformer is arranged internally and how it is externally wired.

You are establishing a **separately derived service** because the transformer is isolating.  Neutral is defined as the "system conductor *which is grounded*".  So you establish neutral by establishing ground.

In other words, you decide where ground comes from.

From what I know about Spanish electrical systems*, 230V so-called "ground/earth" inside homes is taken from the utility.  It may come as a separate ground wire (**TN-S system**) or it may simply be bootlegged off the neutral wire (**TN-C-S system**).  Both are fraught with danger, the latter especially, because the place where it contacts *actual earth* is far away from your home.  So [aside from wire breaks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE), you can also simply have a "voltage gradient" across the earth from the pole transformer to the dirt around your house. That happens all the time.  That's why Americans put ground rods on every structure.

Sometimes ground is not delivered from the utility and established by a local ground spike (**TT system**). This has its own set of risks - neutral from the utility can be quite a different voltage from local earth, and that can get you in big trouble if you don't have RCDs on the supply.

### Gronding/bonding is complicated

So for you.  On one hand, consider **modified TT**, American style.  You establish a local ground rod/earth spike.  You tie that into 115V neutral with a local neutral-ground equipotential bond.  OK.

The gotcha with that system is that if it's in the same house with a TN-S or TN-C-S system, your utility "earth" may be quite a different voltage than your 115V "ground", because of voltage gradients across the earth.  So now you can get zapped by touching both 230V earth and 115V ground, *and the RCDs will just laugh at you for your foolishness*.    However if your house has a 230V TT system, that's exactly what you should do.

The other option is tie the 115V neutral/ground to the utility-supplied **TN-S or TN-C-S** earth.  In this case, the 115V ground will be the same voltage as the 230V earth - however, both of these could be a different voltage than the actual earth around your house.

Isn't European grounding/bonding FUN?

Which is right for you depends on your local circumstances and plans of usage. The European logic is generally that it doesn't matter if system neutral/earth has a voltage difference from actual dirt, since people inside their homes are not touching dirt, and many live in flats where they aren't likely to be [using outdoor appliances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZVx7GbAwlg).  (well they might touch *water pipes*, hello).  But they have many strategies - *or more accurately, work-arounds* - for dealing with this.   Whatever plan you do must be done in correspondance to existing practices, so you don't create a problem.  There is no "pat answer".

Comment: I’ll have to review with an electrician when I return to Spain in a few months. I recall there’s a differential breaker installed on the 230v service in the power panel.